# Manage Roleprovider for two or more tables in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-authorization

I'm making a website using Asp.net mvc4 & EF6 where I've two tables for admins & users and I want to set roles for Authorization for each of them.

So far I've successfully managed to set role for `users` but I can't figure how to set role in my custom `RoleProvider` class if I've two or more models. Here are my codes:

```
public class MgtRoleProvider : RoleProvider
{
    public override string[] GetRolesForUser(string username)
    {
        rental_dbEntities db = new rental_dbEntities();
        string userRole = db.TblUsers.Where(a => a.username == username).FirstOrDefault().role;
        string[] result = { userRole };
        return result;
    }
}
```

How can I set two or more models and return their role values in `GetRolesForUser` method?

Comment: You want to pass in multiple usernames into the method?

Comment: I want to return the role value for multiple models.

Comment: The whole point in ASP.NET identity having user roles and claims is that you don't need multiple tables for your users.  What's stopping you from having an `administrator` role?  Do the usernames for an admin and non-admin exist in both tables or something?

Comment: `TblUsers` contains only user's record, I've another model `TblAdmins` for admin's record. How can I add the admin model in this method so that Authorization can be done for both users & admins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add in a second query for your `TblAdmins` table and return them both:

```
public class MgtRoleProvider : RoleProvider
{
    public override string[] GetRolesForUser(string username)
    {
        rental_dbEntities db = new rental_dbEntities();
        string userRole = string.Empty;
        string adminRole = string.Empty;

        var user = db.TblUsers.Where(a => a.username == username).FirstOrDefault()

        if (user != null)
        {
            userRole = user.role;
        }

        var admin = db.TblAdmins.Where(a => a.username == username).FirstOrDefault();       

        if (admin != null)
        {
             adminRole = admin.role;
        }

        string[] result = { userRole, adminRole };
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm getting a `null` error for `adminRole` if I login as user, and for `userRole` if I login as admin.

Comment: Check for nulls as in the updated code.  I hope this helps

Comment: Yes this works, just a small correction. It should be `var user & var admin` instead of `string user & string admin`.